# How to implement GridView which contains (3rx7c) images with Fragment concept in Android

Tags: android, gridview, fragment

I'm working on Photo Browser in Android. Later I have to add this app in my root application.

I have to use Fragment concept to display the images in gridview, which contains 3 rows & 7 columns.

How two Fragments can communicate via Activity ? Can I have any example to check ??

I'm new to Android.. So, please tell me the process to start.. Thanks !!

Comment: Have you read the [resources](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)? There is also a sample to do download and test.

Answer (score 1):

Start by reading this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html it explains all what you are asking about
And this is for the grid view: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html